# Ansible invoking aws_s3 windows host in block/rescue failed error which hard to understand

Tags: ansible

this block working fine in Linux ! 
i trying to use aws_s3 to download package and using fall back to download from web if its fail 
but im getting error which is hard to understand and pin point the couse of the error :
i present only the prablematic code as it is pard of very big ansible project :

```
- name: Download package
  block:
    - name: Download package from S3
      aws_s3:
        bucket: s3_pack
        object: "{{ package_url | regex_replace('^.*\\.[a-zA-Z]+\/', '') }}"
        dest: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/"
        mode: get
  rescue:
    - name: Download package from FTP
      get_url:
        url_username: xxxxx
        url_password: xxxxx
        dest: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/"
        url: "{{ package_url }}"
```

and this is the error:

```
TASK [package_deploy : Download package from S3] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /main.yml:74
Friday 17 April 2020  09:44:09 +0000 (0:00:01.608)       0:04:08.479 **********
<10.0.6.69> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: Administrator on PORT 5116 TO 10.0.6.6
checking if winrm_host 10.0.6.69 is an IPv6 address
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
Using module file /home//lib64/python3.6/dist-packages/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/aws_s3.py
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
fatal: [10.0.6.69]: FAILED! => changed=false
  module_stderr: |-
    Exception calling "Create" with "1" argument(s): "At line:4 char:21
    + def _ansiballz_main():
    +                     ~
    An expression was expected after '('.
    At line:12 char:27
    +     except (AttributeError, OSError):
    +                           ~
    Missing argument in parameter list.
    At line:14 char:7
    +     if scriptdir is not None:
    +       ~
    Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.
    At line:21 char:7
    +     if sys.version_info < (3,):
    +       ~
    Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.
    At line:21 char:30
    +     if sys.version_info < (3,):
    +                              ~
    Missing expression after ','.
    At line:21 char:25
    +     if sys.version_info < (3,):
    +                         ~
    The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
    At line:23 char:32
    +         MOD_DESC = ('.py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE)
    +                                ~
    Missing expression after ','.
    At line:23 char:33
    +         MOD_DESC = ('.py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE)
    +                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Unexpected token 'imp.PY_SOURCE' in expression or statement.
    At line:23 char:32
    +         MOD_DESC = ('.py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE)
    +                                ~
    Missing closing ')' in expression.
    At line:23 char:46
    +         MOD_DESC = ('.py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE)
    +                                              ~
    Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    Not all parse errors were reported.  Correct the reported errors and try again."
    At line:6 char:1
    + $exec_wrapper = [ScriptBlock]::Create($split_parts[0])
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParseException

    The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command
    name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.
    At line:7 char:2
    + &$exec_wrapper
    +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadExpression
  module_stdout: ''
  msg: |-
    MODULE FAILURE
    See stdout/stderr for the exact error
  rc: 1

TASK [package_deploy : Download package from FTP] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /main.yml:81
Friday 17 April 2020  09:44:12 +0000 (0:00:02.549)       0:04:11.028 **********
Using module file /home//lib64/python3.6/dist-packages/ansible/modules/net_tools/basics/get_url.py
<10.0.6.69> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: Administrator on PORT 5116 TO 10.0.6.6
checking if winrm_host 10.0.6.69 is an IPv6 address
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
fatal: [10.0.6.69]: FAILED! => changed=false
  module_stderr: |-
    Exception calling "Create" with "1" argument(s): "At line:4 char:21
    + def _ansiballz_main():
    +                     ~
    An expression was expected after '('.
    At line:12 char:27
    +     except (AttributeError, OSError):
    +                           ~
    Missing argument in parameter list.
    At line:14 char:7
    +     if scriptdir is not None:
    +       ~
    Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.
    At line:21 char:7
    +     if sys.version_info < (3,):
    +       ~
    Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.
    At line:21 char:30
    +     if sys.version_info < (3,):
    +                              ~
    Missing expression after ','.
    At line:21 char:25
    +     if sys.version_info < (3,):
    +                         ~
    The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
    At line:23 char:32
    +         MOD_DESC = ('.py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE)
    +                                ~
    Missing expression after ','.
    At line:23 char:33
    +         MOD_DESC = ('.py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE)
    +                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Unexpected token 'imp.PY_SOURCE' in expression or statement.
    At line:23 char:32
    +         MOD_DESC = ('.py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE)
    +                                ~
    Missing closing ')' in expression.
    At line:23 char:46
    +         MOD_DESC = ('.py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE)
    +                                              ~
    Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    Not all parse errors were reported.  Correct the reported errors and try again."
    At line:6 char:1
    + $exec_wrapper = [ScriptBlock]::Create($split_parts[0])
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParseException

    The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command
    name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.
    At line:7 char:2
    + &$exec_wrapper
    +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadExpression
  module_stdout: ''
  msg: |-
    MODULE FAILURE
    See stdout/stderr for the exact error
  rc: 1
        to retry, use: --limit @/home//ansible/site.retry

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
10.0.6.69                  : ok=16   changed=13   unreachable=0    failed=2
localhost                  : ok=12   changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have your `ansible_python_interpreter` set to PowerShell or something similarly bad; for extreme clarity, using Windows as the **control host** is not supported: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#control-node-requirements

They have instructions saying you *may* get away with using WSL, but it's not supported: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/windows_faq.html#can-ansible-run-on-windows

Comment: Thanks for your answer , mybe you know how should i download from s3 using user/password as it not public?

Comment: also found this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49941248/windows-server-2012-r2-and-aws-s3-download-from-ansible